# Where are temporary files used for installation stored?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Where are installation temporary files stored by pacman in Arch Linux?

Answer (score 4):

Cache files are stored within `/var/cache/pacman` and its subdirectories, although this can be changed with the `CacheDir` directive in `/etc/pacman.conf`.